# An apple iphone app store style photo slider in query

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, cordova, jquery-mobile, phonegap-plugins

I am looking for a jQuery plugin to help me design an image slider like the image slider used in iphone iOS 6 app store app. This app uses a slider to show screenshots of apps.

cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several slideshow plugins available,

For example 
[PhotoSwipe](http://www.photoswipe.com/) - and a link to their [example pages](http://www.photoswipe.com/latest/examples/04-jquery-mobile.html)

[Diapo slideshow](http://www.pixedelic.com/plugins/diapo/)

Or Diapo's successor [Camera Slideshow](http://www.pixedelic.com/plugins/camera/)

Comment: actually I had already looked into photoswipe. But the problem is it takes up the entire page, I just need a slider in a div without taking over the screen.

Comment: Did you look at the other plugins I linked to?

Comment: I did... but I don't know if it is possible to configure these plugins to look and feel like the read deal (I'm really hung up on app store screenshot slider, if you haven't seen it yet, you should!)